gitlab runners on fargate
I have followed the example here: https://github.com/aws-samples/cdk-fargate-gitlab-runner
And it is working well. However, in order to use any of the security features of gitlab such as DAST/Dep Scanning etc. apparently it needs the docker executor.
Currently I am having to use the custom executor in order to deal with fargate.
Example error in pipeline:
$ /analyzer run
bash: line 163: /analyzer: No such file or directory
ERRO[2024-05-07T10:03:20Z] Application execution failed PID=xxxxx
error="executing the script on the remote host: executing script on
container with IP \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\": executing script: executing
remote script: executing SSH command: Process exited with status 1"

This is not an SSH issue.
Has anyone had any experience of this? and any resolutions please?
Many thanks
